# Javascript data structure: Set of page widths with associated values

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to get a set of classes associated with different window widths. These class-to-width pairs are set by the user. However, I can't find the correct data structure to store it. I believe a tuple would be the optimal type but apparently [they don't exist in javascript](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/accessing-tuples-array-939473.html). If they did my data would looks like this:

```
var pageBreaks = [(900, "foo"), (600, "bar")];
```

Where at 900px I could apply the "foo" class. 600px I could apply "bar". I need to be able to access both the "key" and "value" in an .each() loop.

I could use nested arrays such as `var pageBreaks = [[900, "foo"], [600, "bar"]];` but I think it is very ugly especially trying to get users of my plugin to adopt the format.

An object is possible:

```
var pageBreaks = {
    900 : "foo",
    600 : "bar",
 }
```

But it would be more messy to loop through and it would be easier to process if I keep it ordered greatest to least which isn't guaranteed in an object (right?).

**So what would be the best data structure to handle this array of "value-value" pairs with both sides accessible in a loop?**

Comment: Why don't you do the inverse? `{ "foo": 900, "bar": 600 }`

Comment: Then use `[tuple(900, "foo"), tuple(600, "bar")]` where `tuple=Array`

Comment: Could you not just do this with CSS and change the element style on the breakpoint depending on its base class?  Seems like un-necessary processing for Javascript

Comment: @TheProHands I'm not sure what the inverse would be?

Comment: @Bergi Possible but that seems as messy as the nested array input does it not?

Comment: Btw, if this is user input, it isn't guaranteed to be ordered anyway, so you might just want to preprocess the visually appeasing object literal into the structure that you need.

Comment: @Alex This is being used in a plugin I'm making. I need the "class" and width set to be customizable by the user at time of the init.

Comment: @DasBeasto I meant you could choose the class name as such width.

Comment: @Bergi Also yes the user input isn't a guarantee but this will be a documented setting in the plugin so if the dev setting it up messes it up then I can't really cover for that. They will need to follow the designed structure.

Comment: @DasBeasto: Better make it easy for the dev and deal with messed up input as well. You *can* cover for that. Nothing says the input must match the structure you are using inside your plugin.

Comment: @Bergi true, but validation and error checking is comes after getting the correct structure in the first place (what I'm trying to do here). that's why I'm trying to find something less messy so it'll be harder to mess up. I can't make sure they get it right if I don't have the code set up in the first place haha.

Comment: @TheProHands The way I have it (mentally) set up now is I loop through the structure and say (for example), if less than 900 apply foo, if less than 600 apply bar, etc. I'm not entirely sure doing the inverse would make that different in my situation? Either way I need to easily access both sides. But I will think on it.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could be a good approach, assuming you have access to the newer JS syntax:

```
let pageWidths = new Map();
pageWidths.set(900, "foo");
pageWidths.set(600, "bar");

// ordered
const orderedWidths = new Map([...pageWidths.entries()].sort());

// iteration with forEach
orderedWidths.forEach(console.log.bind(console));

// iteration with for...of
for (var [key, value] of orderedWidths) { 
   console.log(key, value); 
}
```

Even though it will not maintain order on its own (no built-in JS data structure will do that for you*), Maps are fairly easy to work with and easy to accomplish your goals with.

* unless you are using arrays with the pageWidth integer as the index, but even that would require a bit of work to filter out `undefined` elements between them

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hashmap data structure to achieve your goal here. I wrote (am writing) a data structure library in JavaScript, and have already finished the [Hashmap portion](https://github.com/nickzuber/needle#hashmap) if you're interested in using it.

You're able to store key-value pairs (or in your case, value-value pairs) and iterate through them in the same order that they were inserted.

```
const Hashmap = require('node-needle').Hashmap;

var map = new Hashmap();

map.put(900, "foo");
map.put(600, "bar");
// ...

// Iterate through map - insertion order is kept
for(var it = map.iterator(); it !== null; it = map.next()){
  console.log(it);          // 900 -> 600 -> ...
  console.log(map.get(it)); // "foo" -> "bar" -> ...
}
```